# Visual Studio, how to finish up solution and deploy?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nugetgallery

I'm an CS intern working at a company that primarily develops using .NET and Microsoft. I've been using Visual Studio sparsely, and now I'm kind of stuck.

I tried building a NugetGallery using IIS EXpress, and the nuget feed works.

> http://localhost:88/PSGallery/ gives me my nuget feed alright.

But how I do I finish up in Visual Studio? I can run this with VS, but the instant I close VS, my website goes down. I've tried building it and I think it only outputs

> NugetPowerShellGallery\NugetHost\bin\NugetHost.dll

What am I supposed to do with this? How do I make it just run indefinitely?

On a sidenote, how can I display this website on the local network as http://JohnS/PSGallery/

Comment: You probably want to publish it to an IIS server somewhere.

Comment: I think you need to sit down with one of your fellow devs and I'm sure he'll be happy to explain how those things are done at his company. They have all that stuff sorted I'm sure.